# Send IRepository model dependency while reading data from Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, autofac

In my app I use Autofac ContainerBuilder which register my repositories...

I also have a CustomerModel class which represents MongoDB collection. It also has IRepository dependency for other domain model:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    private readonly IRepository<OrderModel> _ordeRepository;

    public CustomerModel(IRepository<OrderModel> ordeRepository)
    {
        _ordeRepository = ordeRepository;
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id;

    public string Email;

    ...

    public List<OrderModel> Orders
    {
        get { return _ordeRepository.List(x => x.CustomerId == Id); }
    }
}
```

How can I inject IRepository<> dependency when I reading data from Mongo?

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IList<TEntity> List(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);
}

public class MongoRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    public IList<TEntity> List(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        IMongoCollection<TEntity> collection = ...;
        return collection.FindSync(expression).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to blend your two repositories within a single context to return an object?

Comment: Generally speaking - Yes. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Are you trying to mix the repository so that when you call a customer the order aspect is built into the customer when you build your customer?  To condense database calls?

Comment: Yes. It`s like a POCO object in Entity framework.

Comment: Will you ever have a customer without an order?  Or will you always expect to have both associated? I inquire because in Dapper you can build a complex object `dbConnection.Query<CustomerModel>(query, (customers, orders, customers) => { customers.Orders = orders; return customers; });` So I would imagine something similar in Entity Framework rather than trying to force two repositories that have specific implementations together.

Comment: It is just a sample case... But generally - it do not have to be loaded in one query. The idea to use this property on demand. It`s a design approach which I trying to keep in my software solution.

Comment: But a model should never perform an action, that creates magic.  If someone builds a brand new customer model then calls order it has hit the database directly from the repository inside a model property.  Generally not typical software behavior or architecture.  Does not follow KISS, SOLID, or CLEAN.  That is my thoughts, I am happy to speak more about it in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183173/discussion-between-maksym-voronytskyi-and-greg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have implementation directly associated to your property.  The reason, an entity is a representation of your data, an entity does not care how the item is stored or created.  Simply a representation of your business object.

The other issue is you violate more common practice in following domain driven design, per Martin Fowler and Evans definition.  One of the largest offenses would be the fact you have forced logic in a property, if you call the property then you automatically hit your database.

As denoted from the C# in depth authors:

> For every type you write, you should consider its interface to the
>   rest of the world (including classes within the same assembly). This
>   is its description of what it makes available, its outward persona.
>   Implementation shouldn't be part of that description, any more than it
>   absolutely has to be. (That's why I prefer composition to inheritance,
>   where the choice makes sense - inheritance generally exposes or limits
>   possible implementations.)
>
> A property communicates the idea of "I will make a value available to
>   you, or accept a value from you." It's not an implementation concept,
>   it's an interface concept. A field, on the other hand, communicates
>   the implementation - it says "this type represents a value in this
>   very specific way". There's no encapsulation, it's the bare storage
>   format. This is part of the reason fields aren't part of interfaces -
>   they don't belong there, as they talk about how something is achieved
>   rather than what is achieved.
>
> I quite agree that a lot of the time, fields could actually be used
>   with no issues in the lifetime of the application. It's just not clear
>   beforehand which those times are, and it still violates the design
>   principle of not exposing implementation.

To handle your implementation while adhering to design principles might be better suited in the following approach and or architecture style.  Please remember, patterns are not cookie cutter.  They solve specific issues for specific reasons, they introduce complexity and problems of their own.  You must weigh the merit of the solution based on your application.

```
// Repositories:
public interface ICustomerRepository : IDisposable
{
     IEnumerable<CustomerModel> RetrieveAllCustomers();

     CustomerModel RetrieveCustomerWithOrders(int id);
}

// Context:
public class CustomerContext : ICustomerRepository
{
     private bool disposed = false;
     private readonly IDbConnection dbConnection;

     public CustomerContext(IConfiguration configuration) => dbConnection = configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnection");

     public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> RetrieveAllCustomers() => dbConnection.Query<CustomerModel>(query);

     public CustomerModel RetrieveCustomerWithOrders(int id) => dbConnection.Query<CustomerModel, OrderModel, CustomerModel>(query, (customer, order) =>
     {
          customer.Orders = order;
          return customer;
     }, new { CustomerId = id });

     public virtual bool Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         if(!disposed)
         {
              if(disposing)
                  dbConnection.Dispose();

              disposed = true;
         }
     }

     public void Dispose() 
     {
          Dispose(true);
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
     }

     ~CustomerContext() => Dispose(true);     
}

// Factory:
public class CustomerFactory : ICustomerFactory
{
     private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

     public CustomerFactory(IConfiguration configuration) => this.configuration = configuration;

     public ICustomerRepository InstantiateCustomer() => new CustomerContext(configuration);
}

public interface ICustomerFactory
{
     ICustomerRepository InstantiateCustomer();
}
```

So we have created some abstraction, we have built our container, we have clear contracts with appropriate implementations.  So if someone is to now use what you have built it would look like the following:

```
public class CustomerService
{
     private readonly ICustomerFactory customerFactory;
     private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

     public CustomerService(ICustomerFactory customerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
     {
          this.customerFactory = customerFactory;
          this.configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> GetAllCustomers()
     {
         using(var customerContext = customerFactory.InstantiateCustomer(configuration))
              return customerContext.RetrieveAllCustomers();
     }

     public CustomerModel GetCustomerOrders(CustomerModel customer)
     {
          using(var customerContext = customerFactory.InstantiateCustomer(configuration))
              return customerContext.RetrieveCustomerWithOrders(customer.Id);
     }
}
```

So when they interface with your service implementation it will create clarity, but will also allow for clear, concise, and expressive code flow.  The implementor can clearly see what is happening in the service implementation but is completely oblivious with how the data implementation occurs.

I did not add any error handling or null checks, but hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the approach make sense, do you see the use of Dependency Injection so you can actually stub and test each area, while being abstracted and expressive?

Comment: Absolutely it make sense. But I thinking now how can I deal with my application. Because I have a lot of domain objects with injected repositories which are fetching the data on demand from other Mongo collections. So, I think I have to make right decision now.  Without spending many hours of refactoring existing approach to another one. But you made really good example which I definitely will take into account and come with right solution for my app. Thanks again Greg.

Comment: You are welcome, I am often in the C# chat room if you need help.

Comment: You might want to look at the Data Transfer Object (DTO) pattern.  Might align in current code base with minimal refactoring.